# What defines the sign of transistor rating values?

Tags: transistors, datasheet, negative

Here for example I have attached excerpts from two general purpose PNP transistor datasheets. One of them has negative values, other one positive.

I would like to understand what defines these values to be positive or negative.

P.S. Second one is for 2n3906.

[image]

Comment: It seems to be the way the manufacturer prefer to look at it.

Comment: @Jaden *because PNP and the other is positive because NPN* The question states that both are PNP. If that is actually the case or one of them is "secretly" an NPN is irrelevant to the actual question. The question is about positive and negative numbers for the same parameters for the same (type of) transistor.

Comment: @[Bimpelrekkie](https://electronics.stackexchange.com/users/77865/bimpelrekkie) I see you are correct.  So, I take it their picture shows where they chose the + and the - and the notation \$V_{BE}\ and\ V_{EB}\$ are irrelevent.  Sad day for me.  That is to say "the voltage between these two pins is ABS(x) and you need to look at the picture to know the polarity."

Comment: I've looked at both sheets.  I do not see any definition on how they chose their polarity or current direction.  I invite anyone to school me on where it is in their datasheets!!!

Comment: @Jaden As I state in my answer, some manufacturers use the "more correct" negative \$V_{BEO}\$ for a PNP, others the "easy" positive number and assume that the reader knows that \$V_{BEO}\$ is the reverse voltage of the BE junction and that for a PNP the + needs to be on the Emitter side for forward mode and + on the base side for reverse mode. For experienced engineers it is no big deal, they know what the polarities need to be. Personally I find the negative numbers helpful as I then immediately know that it's a PNP.

Comment: @Bimpelrekkie  That isn't "more correct", that is undefined.  They expect the reader to "know" what the real meaning is.  Point taken, there is not a convention as to which voltage \$V_E\ or\ V_B\$ is subtracted from which in the term \$V_{BE}\ or\ V_{EB}\$. Reader be aware.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The - (or +) sign indicates polarity (voltage) or direction (current).

For voltages you **choose** a - (negative or reference) and a + (positive) node.

For current you **choose** a direction.

Either polarity or direction **is fine** but you must be consistent, so **stick with that choice**.

Here the two manufacturers chose opposite polarities and current directions. That's fine (makes no difference) as long as they're clear about it.

For NPN transistors I have never seen negative voltage ratings like for some manufacturers do for PNPs. That makes sense because an NPN needs a positive Vbe voltage (Vbase > Vemitter) to make it work in active mode.

For a PNP it is the reverse, all polarities are reversed. To make a PNP work (in active mode) Vbe needs to be negative (Vbase < Vemitter). We could call a PNP's Vbe not Vbe but Veb but that would complicate things in comparison to the NPN. It is much easier to just make Vbe negative and all other voltages (Vce_max etc..) negative as well.

So in my opinion using negative voltage ratings for a PNP is "more correct". However some people may get confused about these negative values and then there is nothing wrong with using positive values and just changing the polarities.

Comment: Both of the ratings use the same labeling convention. As I explained in a comment on the question.

Comment: @Jaden Your comment ignores the facts stated by the OP. What makes you think that one of the transistors is NPN?

Comment: The answer must be that one datasheet follows convention of \$V_{BE} = V_B - V_E\ and\ V_{EB} = V_E - V_B\$ and the other does not follow the convention.